# How to link object file (*.o) and static library file (*.a)

Tags: static, linker, g++, compilation

I have 2 object files (`*.o`) and one static library (`*.a`) using g++
How to link these files and become 1 object file (`*.o`)?

Please advice…thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one (rare) case where you shouldn't be using `g++`. Use `ld` directly:

```
ld -r -o combined.o foo.o bar.o libxyz.a
```